# Unity3d OSX build crash when usage memory over 700mb

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I build my Unity3d application for OSX.

But after sometime application crash when memory usage over 700 mb.
It exist limit memory usage for OSX applications? Can I receive memory warnings for OSX applications?

Crash log:

```
Crashed Thread:        20


Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called
*** error for object 0x11667b00: double free


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x961329e6 semaphore_signal_trap + 10
1   com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore   0x91a2d072 MPSignalSemaphore + 118
2   com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x00670303 PlatformSemaphore::Signal() + 19
```

....

```
Thread 20 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x01341208  ecx: 0xb09c1e8c  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xb09c3000  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xb09c1ea8  esp: 0xb09c1e8c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000206  eip: 0x9613869a   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xa0fb51b4
```

UPDATED:

```
Thread 19:
0   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x97449118 bn_sqr_comba8 + 271
1   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x974565e1 bn_sqr_recursive + 257
2   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x97456600 bn_sqr_recursive + 288
3   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x97456358 BN_sqr + 388
4   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x974b3348 BN_mod_mul_montgomery + 84
5   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x974abb50 BN_mod_exp_mont_consttime + 1082
6   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x974aac75 BN_mod_exp_mont + 87
7   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x9748fb33 dh_bn_mod_exp + 126
8   libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x9748fa2f compute_key + 254
9   libssl.0.9.7.dylib              0x94a33531 ssl3_connect + 7530
10  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000d640b ossl_connect_common + 155
11  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000d693d Curl_ossl_connect + 29
12  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000e81a5 Curl_ssl_connect + 53
13  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000c2c7a Curl_http_connect + 90
14  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000cca4e Curl_protocol_connect + 174
15  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000cd367 setup_conn + 535
16  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000cdbd0 Curl_async_resolved + 48
17  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000dc339 Curl_do_perform + 1801
18  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x0018115c WWWCurl::GetURL(char const*) + 668
19  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x0018127c WWWCurl::WWW_ThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 28
20  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x003b6aa1 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 65
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68de13 _pthread_body + 138
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68dd89 _pthread_start + 162
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68be52 thread_start + 34


Thread 20 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9613869a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68ff19 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90ba9eee abort + 156
3   libmono.0.dylib                 0x01341562 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 881
4   libmono.0.dylib                 0x0137ac7e sigabrt_signal_handler + 99
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x949d603b _sigtramp + 43
6   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
7   libmono.0.dylib                 0x0137ac1b sigusr1_signal_handler + 159
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x90ba9eee abort + 156
9   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x96611561 szone_error + 450
10  libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x96611ea8 free_tiny_botch + 94
11  libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x966083f0 szone_free_definite_size + 1561
12  libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x96606e3a free + 301
13  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x9745f924 CRYPTO_free + 49
14  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x9745d163 lh_delete + 62
15  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x97480df6 int_thread_del_item + 102
16  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib           0x97480689 ERR_remove_state + 60
17  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000d4d96 Curl_ossl_close_all + 22
18  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x000d1f33 Curl_close + 211
19  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x00181166 WWWCurl::GetURL(char const*) + 678
20  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x0018127c WWWCurl::WWW_ThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 28
21  com.iphonesoft3g.texaspokermumac    0x003b6aa1 Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) + 65
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68de13 _pthread_body + 138
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68dd89 _pthread_start + 162
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9b68be52 thread_start + 34
```

Application crashed when WWWCurl GetURL.

Comment: The crash log clearly points out that an object is freed twice, apparently in your `PlatformSemaphore` class when calling the `Signal` function. You are not running out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crash reproduced on devices:

MacBookAir 6,2 
OSX 10.10.2 
curl version (7.37.1)

MacBook Pro(Retina, Mid 2012) 
OSX 10.10.2 
curl version (7.37.1)

After update curlib to version 7.41 I cannot reproduce this crash.